# How does Outlook handle old recurring reminders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

Context:

- Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit edition
- Microsoft Office 2007 Outlook

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Make an event that recurs once a week.
2. Wait a week.
3. See that it pops up OK.
4. Wait a month.
5. Notice that it doesn't say that it is a month overdue.

Expected Result:

The usual note that the reminder is [x] weeks overdue.

Actual Result:
Something like "6 days overdue".

Possible Excaberating Issue:

I have many overdue reminders. For the ones that aren't time critical (and all other things being equal), I work by category and age. For example, I do health-related reminders when I'm doing health stuff; if I have 2 health-related reminders, I do the older one first.

Big Question:

How is Outlook supposed to handle this sort of overdue recurring reminder? Is there any way to get Outlook to act the way I expect it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a Microsoftie, there's no way to get Outlook to act the way I want it to (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-outlook/how-does-outlook-handle-old-recurring-reminders/a95eae3d-e4d7-4c36-9623-946483b749be).